# Where can I find the information from the back of a TAC if I don't have a physical copy?

Tags: usa, aeronautical-charts

The Atlanta TAC has a note that says "See back of this chart for procedural information within the Atlanta Class B Airspace":

[image]

If I don't have a physical copy of the TAC - because I'm using a flight planning app, for example - where else can I find the information?

Comment: Might be good to explain that TAC refers to 'Terminal Area Chart' (and not 'Tactical Air Command' for example).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [Fore Flight](https://www.foreflight.com/) you can [Turn On Legends](https://support.foreflight.com/hc/en-us/articles/203309619-How-do-I-view-a-chart-legend-) which will show you the legend information for the map. You may also be able to download the information somewhere else in the application. It will help if you inform us of which app you are using.

In the [documents](http://ipadpilotnews.com/2012/06/how-to-use-documents-in-foreflight-mobile/) section of [Fore Flight](https://www.foreflight.com/) there are some other Atlanta area documents. Im not sure what the back of the cart looks like so I'm not sure if any of them are correct but there is the Atlanta FLY chart and the Atlanta Class B diagram.

Comment: I believe it's the Atlanta Class B Flyaway diagram, not the legend, but I may be wrong.